# How to "mount" a Synology NAS on a Linux Ubuntu server like it is a local disk

Tags: mount, network-attached-storage

I would like to mount a Synology NAS on a Ubuntu server to make appear this space like it would be a local volume for the system, in particular supporting the server users ownership and permissions.
Which protocols (and software implementation for Ubuntu) to use? Also, would USB be faster than Ethernet ?

Context:

- server will host a NextCloud istance (and lot of other stuff, mainly computational.. JupyterHub, VSCode Server, etc..)
- NAS contains the data for NextCloud, and it uses 5 4TB SSD in RAID 6
- everything is backed up to another NAS

I would prefer not to host NextCloud on the NAS itself, but this could be an option too.

Comment: This is more appropriate for our sister site superuser.com, wait a few minutes and it'll be automatically moved there ok. Either way you need to decide if you want a shared filesystem via a NAS or just a dumb bolt-on disk, they're very different things. Out of interest how are you planning to have a five disk R6 array? They normally need an even number of disks.

Comment: Thanks @Chopper3. I didn't know it. In [this figure](https://www.nextinpact.com/article/69642/stockage-on-grimpe-dun-cran-avec-raid-6-10-50-60) they use 5 disks in Raid 6, and even the [Synology calculator](https://www.synology.com/fr-fr/support/RAID_calculator?tab=sata_ssds&drives=3.84%20TB%7C3.84%20TB%7C3.84%20TB%7C3.84%20TB%7C3.84%20TB) doesn't print any "complain" using 5 disks in Raid 6... but I have no experience on this, so I am now left with the dubt... Ok for the migration, thank you again.

Comment: Oh fair enough, I've never done that myself, tend to stick to even numbers but I hope it works out for you, good luck!